Simple tool to estimate molecular dimensions
I would like to know the aproximate dimensions of a given molecule, it does not need to be very accurate.
Is there a free and simple tool to do a rough estimation?
For example, ChemDraw gives you gives you a predicted 1H-NMR, I was looking for something similar
